# Unable to get browser page node-html-to-image

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, puppeteer

I'm trying to use node.js with the node-html-to-image package but am running into problems since today. Yesterday my code worked fine but today without changing anything it's all broken.
I tried creating a fresh project without adding anything but the default node-html-to-image code (right from the readme) but am getting the same errors.

The error:

```
(node:67808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to get browser page
    at Worker.<anonymous> (G:\ONEDRIVE\\{DIRECTORY}\School\html-to-image-test\node_modules\puppeteer-cluster\dist\Worker.js:41:31)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (G:\ONEDRIVE\{DIRECTORY}\School\html-to-image-test\node_modules\puppeteer-cluster\dist\Worker.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:67808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:67808) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This was produced by the following code (this is all of the code in my index.js. there really is nothing more to it)

```
const nodeHtmlToImage = require('node-html-to-image')

nodeHtmlToImage({
  output: './image.png',
  html: '<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>'
})
  .then(() => console.log('The image was created successfully!'))
```

I've tried to add a .catc() at the end of this but that still doesn't work so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Are you doing this from you school's network? Could it be possible that they wipe their onedrive nightly and the image is deleted?

Comment: The error in the question is from a school owned drive yes but I've encountered this exact error on a personal drive too.

Comment: I am seeing the exact same behavior.  I am using puppeteer flags:

    [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
          '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
          '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
          '--no-first-run',
          '--no-zygote',
          '--single-process',
          '--disable-gpu'
     ]


Has anyone had luck with this?